# <script> disturbs bootstrap.css, workarounds?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I really would like to use twitter-bootstrap, and their scaffolding system with the 12 columns - is there a way to get this working properly with for example ember.js and handlebars.js? I recently ran into trouble, because inserted  tags disterb bootstrap.css descriptions like :first-child, my specific situation described below.

So question: Is there a way properly avoid disterbing bootstrap.css when working with for example ember and handlebars, including  tags?

My specific trouble: the `<div class="span9">` misses out on the CSS below, because the  tag picks it up instead, i think...

```
<!-- Using a handlebars code block helper, {{#if}},  -->
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    {{#if controller.currentItem.isDuo}}
    <div class="span9">{{controller.currentItem.text}}</div>
    <div class="span3">{{controller.currentItem.imgText}}</div>
    {{/if}}
</div>

<!-- Rendered HTML from code above (stripped script tag's attributes for readability) -->
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    <script></script>
    <div class="span9"><script></script>00<script></script></div>
    <div class="span3"><script></script>Mask<script></script></div>
    <script></script>
</div>
```

CSS-code in bootstrap.css, relevant to my situation

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: what if you use the `{{#if}}` outside that main div?

Comment: Yeah! That just solved my situational problem, and will work if I update the layout with having offset3 for example (making margin-left: becoming not 0 but something else)! Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, you could override the Bootstrap CSS with :first-of-type  which will skip over the javascript transforms which are causing all the trouble.

Comment: Ah okay geekingreen, hmmm do you see a way to select first-child-not-script tag? Then i could replace every first-child occurence in bootstrap.css and solve the trouble once and for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fixed this by adding and extra `div` right after the diff like this:

```
<!-- Using a handlebars code block helper, {{#if}},  -->
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    {{#if controller.currentItem.isDuo}}
    <div>
        <div class="span9">{{controller.currentItem.text}}</div>
        <div class="span3">{{controller.currentItem.imgText}}</div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.